# mkdir() Java keeps throwing IOException

Tags: java, file, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory in my current working directory with the title of a url. However, I am converting that url to a hash and then to a hexadecimal so the name of the directory I am trying to create is something like 273212b1. However whenever I execute the code it throws an IOException and cannot make the directory. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Even if I do something like File directory = new File ("Users/whatever/Documents" + dirname); it doesn't work.

Comment: What does the exception _say_?

Comment: try to use `directory.mkdirs();`
because maybe you also need some intermediate directories there.. (not just one level directory)

Comment: Make a System.out.println of the full path wher you're attempting to create the file, maybe that gives you a clue about what's wrong

Comment: Post the stack trace. It could be because of permission, disk is full,  etc. Stacktrace should tell the reason

Comment: @hellboy and others `File.mkdir()` doesn't throw any exceptions. He is throwing the IOException *himself*. Do read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't creating a directory using the hash or hex, you are trying to create a directory using the URL. Here's the relevant steps:

The method is called with s = some URL:

```
public static File mkdir(String s) throws IOException
```

You copy the URL into a variable called dirname:

```
String dirname = s;
```

You set s to be a hex of a hash (which does not change the value of dirname):

```
s = Integer.toHexString(dirname.hashCode());
```

You create a File object representing a directory that has a URL for a name:

```
File directory = new File(dirname);
```

When you try to create that directory, it isn't going to work because of all the characters in a URL that aren't valid for directory names.

You should be doing this:

```
File directory = new File(s);
```

Once you solve that problem, you are then going to want to handle the double creation of the directory as follows:

```
if (directory.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Directory already exists!");
} else {
    success = directory.mkdir();
    if (success) {
        System.out.println("Successful");
    } else {
        throw new IOException("can't make directory for " + s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
success = directory.mkdir();
```

and

```
if  (!directory.mkdir())
```

You're creating the directory twice, or trying to. The second time, it will fail, and throw the exception.

Check your logic. It is redundant. You could reduce most of it to

```
if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdir())
{
    throw new IOException(...);
}
```

You don't need all that output.